# Passing model data to partial view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, partial-views

When I create a partial view, and i want to get some model data, i get this error:

[image]

the partial view file is in Pages/Shared folder

the error says that the name Model does not exist in the current context?

I get the same error also adding the @ before Model

[image]

here the code snippet:

```
@model List<Tuple<string, string, bool>>

@{
    foreach (Tuple<string, string, bool> menu in @Model)
    {
        
    }
}
```

this is how i call the partial, this has no problem whatsoever:

```
@{
    var t = new List<Tuple<string, string, bool>>();
    t.Add(Tuple.Create("/Veicoli", "Veicoli", true));
    t.Add(Tuple.Create("/Clienti", "Clienti", false));

}
@section Tabs {
    <partial name="_TabsPartial" model="t" />
}
```

I think maybe the problem is in some configuration in creating the partial view file, how do I fix this?

I expect to be able to access the passed Model in the partial view

Comment: Going forward always include code as code block snippets, not images

Comment: It seems something wrong in your visual studio? Have you created a new project to test if it show this error? I recommend you to restart your vs or update it.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
@foreach (Tuple<string, string, bool> menu in Model
{

}
```

Invoke razor things using the `@` symbol. This will define a block in which C# code is now usable. At runtime, all of these C# expressions will be evaluated and templated into the webpage as HTML, C# backend logic, etc

Your line `@model List<Tuple<string, string, bool>>` will declare a variable for use called Model but since this is a C# object, it must be used as `@Model` *when on its own*

In this case you do not need to use it, as it is if its already wrapped in a `@foreach` razor block

Please give [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) a read for a summary of razor syntax

Comment: it is not working, i get the same error also adding the @

Comment: @Badjem79 My apologies, I made some slight errors. I see your edit on your question, remove the wrapping `@{}` and use `@foreach{}` instead and you *do* use `Model` since its now wrapped in a foreach razor block. I have edited my answer as well to show this. Try it and let me know

Comment: I get the same error, i think visual studio don't consider the file _partialView as a partial view at all or there must be some configuration that I'm missing

Comment: @Badjem79 ok question, how is that model making its way to the partial view? Maybe there is an issue with the controller method for this

Comment: I added the code used to call the partial, it does not show any error...I think maybe the problem is in some configuration in creating the partial view file

Comment: also ViewData is not existent in the context

Comment: Ok so Models are typically used to capture something coming from a controller method. I am still a bit confused as to what you are really doing, but it looks like you should be using `t` instead of Model. You declare the list in razor code as `t`, and therefore it will follow the nomenclature you set. If this were a data model coming from a Controller method in the backend, then you will use `@Model` et al. But effectively you have declared and init the list in the frontend so there is no model to deal with here

Comment: You should be calling `@Html.Partial("_TabsPartial")` or `@Html.Partial("_tabs2")` (there is a disconnect here between the images and code) rather than `@section`. Secondly move the declaration and initialization of `t` either into the Partial itself, or properly into a Controller for proper enforcement of MVC structure. Based on what you choose in that last step, you will then either use `t` if you moved it into the partial view, or `Model` if you moved it into a controller method